# JS Regex to match character outside nested braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex to target commas that exist only outside a pair of brackets or braces.

Currently I have:

```
var regex = /,(?![^{]*})(?![^[]*])/g
```

When the target string is:

```
var str = '"a":[{"b":2,"c":["d"]}],"b":2'    // OK: only second comma matches
```

the pattern correctly matches only the second comma.

When the target string is:

```
var str = '"a":[{"b":2,"c":{"d":9}}],"b":2'    // OK: only second comma matches
```

the pattern also correctly matches only the second comma.

However, when the target string includes a array and object, the negative lookahead fails and the regex matches both commas.

```
var str = '"a":[{"b":2,"c":[{"d":9}]}],"b":2'    // BAD: both commas match
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: As mentioned in this accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/1679286, it would be better to code it, **regex is not the right tool, for this job**.

Comment: Using it to write a JSON parser.

Comment: I've got a solution coded out; just wondering if there's a way to accomplish it more cleanly with a regular expression.

Comment: @RhinoDavid the answer to that is "no"

Comment: Take a look at the JSON2 [parse.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js) Don't see regexs there.

Comment: This has been asked a LOT here. You should be able to search for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ1zP1/1)) with the mentioned example:

```
,(?!([^{]*{[^{]*})?[^{]*})(?!([^[]*\[[^[]*])?[^[]*])
```

But it's **not** a generic regex.

For each level of nested brackets you need to expand the regex. For example, to match also `"a":[{"b":2,"c":[{"d":[{"e":9}]}]}],"b":2` you will need:

```
,(?!([^{]*{([^{]*{[^{]*})?[^{]*})?[^{]*})(?!([^[]*\[([^[]*\[[^[]*])?[^[]*])?[^[]*])
```

[See second demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ1zP1/2).

This is not a scalable solution, but it's the only one with regexes.
Just for curiosity.

Comment: I'd like to know a reason for the downvote.

Comment: it doesn't work in all the cases but nice idea, upvoted